# Division operation is giving me the wrong result

Tags: java, math, processing, division

I'm trying to divide one number by another in Processing, and I keep getting the wrong answer.

```java
float a;
a = 3/2;
println(a);
```

gives me

```java
1.0
```

when then answer should be 1.5.

Trying a different number,

```java
float a;
a = 2/3;
println(a);
```

gives me

```java
0.0
```

when the answer should be 0.666666....

Is there something I'm missing? I looked over the [Processing documentation for division](https://processing.org/reference/divide.html) and it seems like I'm using the right syntax.

Comment: you're dividing integers. Try `3.0/2`.

Comment: Have you tried `a = 3.0/2.0;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, you're using integer division.

Remember that `int` values can't hold decimal places. So if you do a calculation that would result in decimal places, those values are **truncated** and you're left with only the whole number part (in other words, the **integer** part).

```java
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = x/y; //0

int x = 5;
int y = 2;
int z = x/y; //2
```

You're using **int literal values** (digits like `2` and `3`), and those don't have decimal places, so Processing treats them like `int` values, and they obey the above rules.

If you care about the decimal places, then either store them in `float` or `double` variables:

```java
float x = 1;
float y = 2;
float z = x/y; //.5

float x = 5;
float y = 2;
float z = x/y; //2.5
```

Or just use `float` literals by adding a decimal part:

```java
float a = 2.0/3.0;
```

Processing now knows that these are `float` values, so you'll keep the decimal places.

Comment: you actually have to declare a float like this:

(float) x = 5; 

or else php will throw an error.

Comment: @UriahsVictor This is Processing, not PHP.

Comment: ah lol sorry was doing some php when i came across this thread

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Processing is interpreting both `3` and `2` as integers.  And, since you are dividing one integer by another, it is giving you integer division.

Try changing one or both to `3.0` and/or `2.0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your division in interpreted as an integer division and will most probably follow Java integer division rules (since [Processing seem to be based on Java)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language)).

Java inherits most of its division rules from C, these being explained in more details in a specific question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c).